# How to track user changes in the buffer?

Tags: buffers, hooks

I would like to make a mode that would react to user changing the buffer. One way i know is to use hooks.

What hooks, other then `post-self-insert-hook`, should i use?

What changes i am interested in:

- entering text
- changing indentation
- deleting text
- yanking

And maybe, in future, so-to-sy:

- changes in cursor position

In general, some way to react to changes in the buffer would be sufficient.

Comment: The emacswiki has a few ideas you can look at:  https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TrackChanges

Comment: Tracking cursor position changes is a completely different ball game (since every window showing a given buffer has its own `point`): better make a separate question for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To react to buffer changes, you generally want to use `after-change-functions` (or sometimes `before-change-functions`).

These hooks are run everytime some part of the buffer is modified, either by inserting or by deleting a chunk of text (or text-properties).  Be aware that some commands work by applying several modifications to the buffer, so those hooks can be run several (or even many) times in a single command.  So if you need to perform a a significant amount of work, it is often useful to use 2-step approach, where an `after-change-function` only keeps track of the affected region, and then a post-command-hook uses that data to perform the heavy lifting.

E.g.

```
(defvar foo-unhandled-changes nil)
(defun foo-after-change-function (beg end _len)
  "Remember to fixup the text between BEG and END."
  (unless undo-in-progress
    (if foo-unhandled-changes
        (setq foo-unhandled-changes
              (cons (min beg (car foo-unhandled-changes))
                    (max end (cdr foo-unhandled-changes))))
      (setq foo-unhandled-changes (cons beg end)))))
```

then use `(add-hook 'after-change-functions #'foo-after-change-function nil t)` where needed, plus a `post-command-hook` which can use `foo-unhandled-changes` to know which part of the buffer (if any) was modified since last time it was run (and which should reset `foo-unhandled-changes` to nil).